# SimplePie Not Parsing RSS Feed

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplepie

I've been using SimplePie for about 4 yrs now w/Curl...and it's worked great up until 2-6-17.

For the last 12+ hrs I've been trying to narrow down why it won't parse any of craigslists list feeds. I've tried ever possible scenario available. I do get a 200 return with the data, but it includes it with an error.

> is invalid XML, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: Not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 1

Here's the weird thing, it works with fopensocket with no problems.

Here here some of my settings:

> Ubuntu 14.04
>
> Apache/Ngnix
>
> PHP 5.6
>
> Host: VPS DigitalOcean
>
> SimplePie v-1.4.3
>
> $rss = new SimplePie();
>
> $rss->set_feed_url('http://detroit.craigslist.org/search/apa?availabilityMode=0&bedrooms=3&format=rss&min_price=800');
>
> $rss->useragent= 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.1.0.7';
>
> $rss->get_item_quantity( 10 );
>
> $rss->force_feed(true);
>
> $rss->force_fsockopen(false);
>
> $rss->set_input_encoding('UTF-8');
>
> $rss->set_output_encoding('UTF-8');
>
> $rss->init();
>
> $rss->handle_content_type();

Here's the return of the header:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Cache-Control: max-age=900, public Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 18:24:12 GMT Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 18:24:12 GMT Content-Encoding: gzip Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Length: 5991 Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN Server: Apache Expires: Mon, 13 Feb 2017 18:39:12 GMT

I've done a RSS validate and it didn't have any significant errors.

Also, tried it on a brand new server/same settings and got the same result.

They do work on the demo site simplepie.org/demo...so I'm thinking it has something to do with my server settings.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Update: For some reason it's parsing the header inside of the body and in the the application type is text/plain. If I do a print_r($parser); on line 1472 of SimplePie.php returns [error_string] => Not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: Update I've narrowed it down to SimplePie_File Object
        (
            [url] => https://phoenix.craigslist.org/search/zip?format=rss
            [useragent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.1.0.7
            [success] => 1
            [headers] => Array
                (
                )
[body] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=900, public...Expires: Tue, 14 Feb 2017 01:41:31 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! Now works with older proxies
[What to do with extra HTTP header from proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965530/what-to-do-with-extra-http-header-from-proxy)

I added this on line 158 of FILE.php

```
            // cURL automatically handles Proxy rewrites, remove the "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established" string
            $this->headers = explode("\r\n\r\n", $this->headers, $info['redirect_count'] + 1);
            $this->headers = array_pop($this->headers);//$this->headers[0];//
            if (false !== stripos($this->headers, "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n")) { $this->headers = str_ireplace("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n", '', $this->headers);}
```